# Need to access an element by id which isn't accessible until after document.load

Tags: javascript

I am using an external server to load a widget on my page. I want to access that getElementById after it loads. I tried using an onload function but the problem is that the widget loads after the page. Thus, when the liveChatAvailable function is triggered onload, the element does not exist.

Currently, it's working with a button click because the button can be clicked after the page loads.

This is the code loading the liveChat.

```
<script type='text/javascript' data-cfasync='false'>
    window.purechatApi = { 
         l: [],
         t: [], 
         on: function () {
              this.l.push(arguments); 
         } 
    };
   (function () { 
    var done = false; 
    var script = document.createElement('script'); 
    script.async = true;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://app.purechat.com/VisitorWidget/WidgetScript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0).appendChild(script);
    script.onreadystatechange = script.onload = function (e) { 
    if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
        var w = new PCWidget(
        {
            c: '<CODEXXXX>', f: true 
        }); 

        done = true; liveChatAvailable(); 

    } }; })();

 </script>
```

This is the code accessing element by ID.

```
 <script>
    function liveChatAvailable() {
                 var liveChat = document.getElementById("PureChatWidget");
                 if((liveChat.className).includes("purechat-state-unavailable") ){
                     // loadChatbot code is here

                 }
             }
 </script>
```

Strategies that I have tried (shortened):

```
document.body.onload ...
 document.onload ...
body onload = ....
window.AddEventListener ('DOMContentLoaded ...
```

Comment: Run your JS after the DOM loads: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: Please format your code to make it readable.

Comment: `window.onload = function() { var liveChat = document.getElementById("PureChatWidget") }`